# Why can't Windows find a file that's obviously there?

Tags: windows-search

Take a look at this picture. There is a file that's obviously there

[image]

Now, say I tried to find FileZilla or File, or Zilla

[image]

As you see from the same screen shot the file is obviously not there.

So why and how do I fix it? Is the index broken or what? No error message whatsoever.

I want to know I will always be able to find my files.

Comment: This file is in OneDrive placed ?

Comment: yes it is. What difference does it make?

Comment: There might be some problem with one drive. Can you search for all the other files in one drive ?

Comment: there seems to be some problem with index